# padding-top on input element in IE7/8?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS 
http://jsfiddle.net/YDp83/3/

In Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE9 the textbox has a left padding and the text is vertically in the middle but in IE7 and 8 the text is aligned at the top of the textbox, how can I get it to be in the middle vertically like in the other browsers?

I can't alter the HTML but the CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `line-height: 27px` to `input.ms-sbplain`

http://jsfiddle.net/YDp83/4/